# What is the Unity 2 replacement for <typeConfig />?

Tags: generics, configuration, unity-container

As the title states: **what (if available) is the replacement for the `<typeConfig />` element in Unity 2?**

- [Unity 1 config schema reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648769.aspx)
- [Unity 2 config reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx#config_registerelement)

**Or alternatively:** How can I configure a type parameter for a class in Unity configuration?

```
<alias alias="ISomeInterface" type="Namespace.ISomeInterface" />
<alias alias="SomeType" type="Namespace.SomeType`1" />
<alias alias="Foo" type="Namespace.Foo" />
<alias alias="Bar" type="Namespace.Bar" />

<container>
    <register type="ISomeInterface" mapTo="SomeType" name="GenericFoo">
        <!-- define generic type as Foo -->
    </register>
    <register type="ISomeInterface" mapTo="SomeType" name="GenericBar">
        <!-- define generic type as Bar -->
    </register>
</container>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <typeConfig> element was simply removed - it was a layer of XML that didn't actually add anything but noise to the config file. The stuff that you previously nested inside typeConfig (like <constructor>, <param>, etc.) are now placed as children of the <register> element.

As for your example there, you'd need to specify the generic type parameter as part of the mapTo parameter, like so:

```
<register type="ISomeInterface" mapTo="SomeType[Foo]" name="GenericFoo" />
<register type="ISomeInterface" mapTo="SomeType[Bar]" name="GenericBar" />
```

Or you could use the CLR generic type syntax (the version with the `1 etc.) but that's a lot noisier than the shortcut syntax Unity implements here.

NOTE: Of course, the aliases you have above won't work, since you haven't included the assembly names with them, so this solution won't work until you work out those details. Also, consider using the <assembly> and <namespace> declarations in the config file to remove the need for lots of aliases.

Comment: Thanks for the details! I left out the namespace/assembly details for readability, however I forgot to mention that `SomeType` actually has _two_ generic parameters and that `ISomeInterface` actually has _one_. Does the shortcut syntax supply a method to provide one generic parameter through configuration and the other while resolving? `<register type="ISomeInterface`1" mapTo="SomeType[][Foo]" name="GenericFoo" />`